# How to convert an EntityCollection<T> to List<POCOObj>

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have Entity Framework entities Events which have an EntityCollection of RSVP. I want to convert the EntityCollection of RSVP to a generic List<> of a POCO class RSVP.

So I want EntityCollection -> List.

What would be the best way to go about achieving this?

So far I have this (it's missing the RSVP part)

```
var events = from e in _entities.Event.Include("RSVP")
                     select new BizObjects.Event
                     {
                         EventId = e.EventId,
                         Name = e.Name,
                         Location = e.Location,
                         Organizer = e.Organizer,
                         StartDate = e.StartDate,
                         EndDate = e.EndDate,
                         Description = e.Description,
                         CreatedBy = e.CreatedBy,
                         CreatedOn = e.CreatedOn,
                         ModifiedBy = e.ModifiedBy,
                         ModifiedOn = e.ModifiedOn,
                         RSVPs = ???
                     };
```

Thanks.

Comment: Checkout this [Projections and Includes](http://www.thejoyofcode.com/Projection_blows_includes_in_Entity_Framework.aspx) blog post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you put the "select" code into **extension method** named something like "ToPoco(this Event event)" (you will use this for single "Event" conversion).

You must also implement another extension method for multiple "Event" conversion like `List<BizObjects.Event> ToPoco(this List<Event> events)` extension, which just call the `BizObjects.Event Poco(this Event event)` in a loop.

After that your query will look like this:

```
var events = (from e in _entities.Event.Include("RSVP")).ToList().ToPoco();
```

**About RSVPs:**

You just normally create another extension method for RSVP conversion like

`List<BizObjects.RSVP> ToPoco(this List<RSVP> RSVPs)`

Then you can then call `RSVPs = e.RSVPs.ToList().ToPoco()`

---

Solution for directly fit to you code could be also something like that:

```
RSVPs = e.RSVPs.Select(rsvp => new RSVP  { //do mapping })
```

Comment: I tried your last solution, but had to add .ToList to .Select. However, I got an EntityFramework error stating it couldn't convert ToList(). I will post the error later when I get a chance.

You have pointed me in the right direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
    var events = from e in _entities.Event.Include("RSVP")
                 select new BizObjects.Event
                 {
                     EventId = e.EventId,
                     Name = e.Name,
                     Location = e.Location,
                     Organizer = e.Organizer,
                     StartDate = e.StartDate,
                     EndDate = e.EndDate,
                     Description = e.Description,
                     CreatedBy = e.CreatedBy,
                     CreatedOn = e.CreatedOn,
                     ModifiedBy = e.ModifiedBy,
                     ModifiedOn = e.ModifiedOn,
                     RSVPs = from r in e.RSVP
                             select new BizObjects.RSVP
                             {
                                 RSVPId = RSVPId,
                                 // etc.
                             }
                 };
```